# Cover Flow effect using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, coverflow

I want to have coverflow effect using ViewPager. I found [CoverFlowWidget](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html) since its extending Gallery widget which is deprecated its better to go on with `ViewPager` instead.Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently looking on how to do this too.

I think you should use : https://gist.github.com/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1 and add a PageTransformer to the ViewPager.

Comment: I know how to use ViewPager but i dont know How to made it look like CoverFlow?

Comment: With a PageTransformer that change rotationY of pages

Answer (score 1):

Create a container (layout) to house your ViewPager.  Set setClipChildren(false) on both the container and ViewPager.  Set the ViewPager's width to container/2 if you want to show 2 whole pages (1/2 left, 1 center, 1/2 right)

Answer (score 0):

use ViewPager setPageMargin to make offscreen pages visible at the same time. Then use setPageTransformer to make cover flow animation.